# Validate more than 3 cells in Datagridview VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How can I validate 4 entered cells if they exist in the same datagridview, at the time of writing in the 4 cell cell

So people my datagriview

```
   Sub listar_CC_configurados()
    dtc = Negcc.Listar_CC_configurados(VGlobales.Base)

    For Each data As DataRow In dtc.Rows
        Dim aa As Integer = Me.dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows.Add()
        'Me.dgv1.Rows(aa).Cells(0).Value = data("ACCION").ToString().Trim
        Me.dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows(aa).Cells(0).Value = data("IDSUCURSAL").ToString().Trim
        Me.dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows(aa).Cells(1).Value = data("SUCURSAL").ToString()
        Me.dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows(aa).Cells(2).Value = data("IDALMACEN").ToString()
        Me.dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows(aa).Cells(3).Value = data("ALMACEN").ToString()
        Me.dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows(aa).Cells(4).Value = data("IDCC").ToString()
        Me.dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows(aa).Cells(5).Value = data("CC").ToString()
        Me.dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows(aa).Cells(6).Value = data("PERIODO_INICIO").ToString()
        Me.dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows(aa).Cells(7).Value = data("PERIODO_FIN").ToString()



    Next
End Sub
```

In the CellEndit event, I perform the validation only of cell No. 4 as follows

```
    Private Sub dgvlistccconfigurados_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvlistccconfigurados.CellEndEdit
    Dim clave As String
    Dim nlinea As Integer

    If e.ColumnIndex = 4 Then
        clave = dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows(dgvlistccconfigurados.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(4).Value.ToString
        nlinea = dgvlistccconfigurados.CurrentRow.Index
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows.Count - 1
            If clave = dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString And i <> nlinea Then
                dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows(nlinea).Cells(4).Value = ""
                MsgBox("esta repetido el codigo")
                SendKeys.Send("{UP}")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Now I can't find a way to validate the 4 cells you enter if they exist in the same datagridview, I can only do it with the 4 cell.

Any idea what I would be missing to perform this requirement?

[image]

I am applying the following code but it gives me an error

```
   Private Sub dgvlistccconfigurados_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvlistccconfigurados.CellEndEdit
    Dim clave As String
    Dim suc, almacen As String

    Dim nlinea As Integer

    If e.ColumnIndex = 4 Then
        clave = dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows(dgvlistccconfigurados.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(4).Value.ToString
        suc = dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows(dgvlistccconfigurados.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(0).Value.ToString
        almacen = dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows(dgvlistccconfigurados.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(2).Value.ToString
        nlinea = dgvlistccconfigurados.CurrentRow.Index
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows.Count - 1
            If Convert.ToString(clave And suc And almacen) = Val(dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value And dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value And dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value) And i <> nlinea Then
                dgvlistccconfigurados.Rows(nlinea).Cells(4).Value = ""
                MsgBox("esta repetido el codigo")
                SendKeys.Send("{UP}")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

**Conversion of string to type 'Long' is invalid.**

[image]

Comment: Don't perform validation on the `CellEndEdit` event. There's a `CellValidating` event for a reason. If you want to validate multiple cells though, you'd be better of using the `RowValidating` event. How can you know what order the user will populate those cells?

Comment: Is `Convert.ToString(clave And suc And almacen)` supposed to be concatenating strings? If so then `&` is the concatenation operator, which you should already know. We shouldn't have to guess what that code is supposed to be doing. ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. We can't tell you what code should look like if we don't know what it's supposed to do and we shouldn't have to assume or guess what that is from code that doesn't do it.